# How to make the Combobox item list dynamic?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am using a 'Generate' button on my worksheet. When I click on the button, a popup (form) come, which contains two comboboxes. Basis the selection in the first combobox, the second combobox option list is populated.

For the first combobox, when I hardcode the item values it works fine. The form code is as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ComboBox_DL
    .AddItem "DL1"
    .AddItem "DL2"
End With

End Sub
```

I tried to make this item list dynamic by fetching the combobox item values from a column the in the excel worksheet using the following form code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ComboBox_DL
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range(Range("AE"), Range("AE").End(xlDown))
 .AddItem c.Value
Next
End With

End Sub
```

But the above code throws error: Run time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

```
I modified the code adding sheet details: 
With ComboBox_DL
    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Business_Input_Data").Range(Range("AE"), Range("AE").End(xlDown))
        .AddItem c.Value
Next
```

It still throws the same error.

Can someone help please? Also, I want to know how to look up the values corresponding to the selection in combobox1 and populate the list in combobox2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your combobox entries are a list on a worksheet, you don't need to use VBA to fill them at all. Instead, you can create a Dynamic Named Range, and use that as the Rowsource for the combobox.

Say your list starts on Sheet3, cell A1. Go to Formulas | Name Manager to create a named range. Give it a useful name like "Combo", then put the following formula into RefersTo: `=OFFSET(Sheet3!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet3!$A:$A),1)` Save and close the Named Ranges dialogue.

In the properties of your combobox, look for the line "RowSource". Set it to `=Combo`, or whatever name you used for your named range.

Any changes to the list, including lengthening or shortening it, will now be reflected immediately and automatically in the combo box.

EDITED TO ADD:

To use the value selected in the first combobox to determine what list is used in a second combobox, we'll need to do two things.

The first is to create named ranges for all the possible selections in the first list:
[image]

In the image, column A is the source for our first combo box; the other columns contain the possible sources for the second combo box.

We then just need to put a little bit of code in the Change event for the first combobox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.ComboBox2.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox2.RowSource = "=" & Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

This code will trigger whenever ComboBox1 is changed. First it clears any existing value in ComboBox2, then it will set the row source property of ComboBox2 to a combination of the `=` symbol and whatever value was selected in the first box. Since those values are also named ranges, the second box will now use the selected named range as its list source.

If you needed to, you could add more levels of cascading options, with different named ranges for each one. More than a couple of levels may become unmanageable, though - at which point we may want to look at another method.

Comment: Thanks Werf. How about the displaying the second combobox that would contain a list basis the selection in the first combobox?

Comment: Normally, if we were doing this with data validation dropdowns, we'd just say create other named ranges based on the possible values in your first range, and use an indirect formula pointing to the result of the first one as the source for the others. With Comboboxes on forms, it's a little more complex; I'll edit to include some code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Havent tested this as i have not created the userform to test under same conditions, but should work subject to minor alterations.

```
Dim n As Long
n = Sheets("Business_Input_Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Row

With ComboBox_DL
    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Business_Input_Data").Range("AE" & n)
        .AddItem c.Value
Next
```

Comment: Thanks mo.h How about the displaying the second combobox that would contain a list basis the selection in the first combobox? Assuming I have a table for DL names and corresponding combobox2 list options?

Comment: not a problem! mark this as an answer if you found it useful :). Regarding your question above, what do you mean? please clarify

Comment: In the same form I have another combobox2 which lists values depending on what I select in combobox1. Say DL1 corresponds to A1, B1, C1 items. And DL2 corresponds to A2, B2, C2. In case I select DL1 in combobox 1, combobox should list only the options A1, B1 and C1. Similarly for DL2 selected in combobox1, combbox2 should list A2, B2 and C2.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the row index in "AE"
furthermore use always explicit worksheet qualification in any `Range` reference

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim c As Range

    With ComboBox_DL
        For Each c In For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Business_Input_Data").Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Business_Input_Data").Range("AE1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Business_Input_Data").Range("AE1").End(xlDown))
         .AddItem c.Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

but more elegant solutions are:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()        
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Business_Input_Data")
        ComboBox_DL.RowSource = .Range("AE1", .Range("AE1").End(xlDown)).Address
    End With        
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()        
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Business_Input_Data")
        ComboBox_DL.List = .Range("AE1", .Range("AE1").End(xlDown)).Value
    End With        
End Sub
```

where:

- the former *binds* your `ComboBox` list to the range values whose address is given as `ComboBox` `RowSource` property
- the latter takes the values of the given range as `Combobox` values

Comment: Thanks for this. How to populate only specific values in combobox 2 basis the selection in combobox1?

Comment: this is a new issue, then post a new question

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to dynamically update the comboBox with emails in one column range.

```
    Dim c As Range

ComboBox1.Value = ""
ComboBox1.Clear
For Each c In Sheets("emails").Range("F5:F5000")
    If c Like "*@*" Then
        ComboBox1.AddItem c
    End If
Next
```

The 'ComboBox.Value' Set the initial value.
The 'ComboBox.Clear' Clears the previous rows in the comboBox.