# Simple Dynamic UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to create ComboBox that list the not empty values in the dynamically changed range from C5 to last not empty column in the row "C". Thanks to [user3598756](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612417/how-to-make-the-combobox-item-list-dynamic) I build below solution but I get the error "Permission denied" when using both code blocks: ComboBox1.RowSource and ComboBox.List.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wsRoadmap As Worksheet
    
    Set wsRoadmap = Sheets("Roadmap")
    
    With wsRoadmap
        ComboBox1.RowSource = .Range("C5", .Range("DJ5").End(xlToLeft)).Address
    End With
    
    With wsRoadmap
        ComboBox1.List = .Range("C5", .Range("DJ5").End(xlToLeft)).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: When I erase it only first cell is listed, not the whole range...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add items to combobox from columns then use this code -

Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

```
Dim TCol As Long, CCol As Long
Dim wsRoadmap As Worksheet

Set wsRoadmap = Sheets("Roadmap")

TCol = wsRoadmap.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Me.ComboBox1.Clear

'loop from column C to the last used column of 5th row
For CCol = 3 To TCol
    
    If VBA.Trim(wsRoadmap.Cells(5, CCol).Value) <> "" Then
    
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem wsRoadmap.Cells(5, CCol).Value
    
    End If
    
Next CCol
```

End Sub

but if you want to add items to combobox from rows then use this code-

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

```
Dim TRow As Long, CRow As Long
Dim wsRoadmap As Worksheet

Set wsRoadmap = Sheets("Roadmap")

TRow = wsRoadmap.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Me.ComboBox1.Clear

For CRow = 5 To TRow
    
    If VBA.Trim(wsRoadmap.Cells(CRow, 3).Value) <> "" Then
    
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem wsRoadmap.Cells(CRow, 3).Value
    
    End If
    
Next CRow
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you Virendra. Can you please advice how implement second Combobox which list specific range depends on the selection in first combo box. I have in row 5 some merged cells. Beneath in row 6 I have sub categories. I want to list the sub categories depends on the selection in the first combobox? Shall I create a new topic, so that I could rate your effort?

Comment: Welcome. Yes you can add 2nd combobox which lists specific range depends on the first selection. can you please send me screenshot of your excel sheet? so I can write code for you. and please create new topic for this. Thank you.